# Reference request: All types over $\mathbb{R}$ in $(\mathbb{R},+,·)$ are definable.

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic, model-theory

I found a proof of this fact in the paper *Tarski's problem and Pfaffian functions* by Lou van den Dries published in Logic Colloquium 84.

I was wondering if there are more direct (or more elementary) proofs of this fact because the papers I found they all reference this original one by van den Dries.

Comment: Are you familiar with o-minimality? Do you only care about types in one variable, or do you need the result for arbitrary $n$-types?

Comment: I am familiar with the basics of o-minimality. I would like a result for arbitrary n-types if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:** Let $M$ be a Dedekind complete o-minimal structure. Then every type in $S_n(M)$ is definable over $M$.

When $n = 1$, the result is a fairly straightforward consequence of o-minimality. For a sketch of a proof, see Lemma 2.4.4 of *[Notes on o-minimality and variations](http://library.msri.org/books/Book39/files/mac.pdf)* by Dugald Macpherson.

The proof for general $n$ is substantially more difficult. It was originally proved in 1994 in the paper *[Definable types in o-minimal theories](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275260)* by Marker and Steinhorn (Corollary 2.2). Pillay gave another proof the same year in the paper *[Definability of types and pairs of o-minimal structures](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275712)* (Theorem 1.1).

You asked for a more direct or more elementary proof, and maybe what I've given you are more abstract or more complicated proofs... I haven't read the proof by van den Dries of the special case over $\mathbb{R}$, but I would be quite surprised if there were a proof over $\mathbb{R}$ that was substantially simpler than the general o-minimal case.

Comment: Wow, I would *not* have guessed that that result was that hard!